# Limiting a for loop in perl

Tags: regex, loops, perl

I have a bit of perl which is taking in data via a pipe and running

```
... | perl -0 -wnE 'say for /\d+/g'
```

which prints every numeric value passed from before the pipe.  How would I change this syntax so that only the last ten found are printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
... | perl -M5.010 -ne'say for /\d+/g' | tail -10
```

```sh
... | perl -nle'print for /\d+/g' | tail -10
```

Perl-only:

```sh
... | perl -M5.010 -ne'push @n, /\d+/g; splice(@n, 0, -10); END { say for @n }'
```

```sh
... | perl -nle'push @n, /\d+/g; splice(@n, 0, -10); END { print for @n }'
```

Notes:

- `-E` isn't forward compatible, meaning that upgrading Perl could break the program. It should only be used in singe-use code. Replaced with `-M5.010 -e`.
- `-0` was an attempt to slurp the input file. That's not what it does. `-0777` should be used for that. But there's no reason to slurp the input file here.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe it through the `tail` unix command to show only the last 10 numbers:

```
... | perl -0 -wnE 'say for /\d+/g' | tail -10
```